# AppStore gambling policy

Tags: ios-appstore

As I understand currently Apple allows some kind of gambling apps to be published on AppStore, I just don't know all about this. So, my question is if they would allow a lotto type app with real money of course but also with virtual currency.

If anyone could shed some light on this I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apples publishes the objective and subjective app review criteria publicly at:

- https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

I see nothing that currently prohibits gambling apps. Also, open up the App Store and search on the term "gambling" and you'll see there are dozens of apps that appear to be identical in function.

Comment: As a side note, there is a clause in the review guidelines that trivial apps may be rejected and if there are already 1000 lotto apps you might have to come up with some compelling code to get it approved.